# Server is failing SSH connections

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, cpanel

Not certain what's happened here, but any SSH connection to my server is failing. Yesterday it was working, today it is not.

> Server: Centos 6.10 cPanel v86.0.18
>   Client: Windows systems using Putty SSH

I am on a Windows machine using Putty. I can connect to the IP on port 22. If I type the wrong password, it gives me the password prompt again. If I provide the correct password it either just closes the session window or gives me an error `Server unexpectedly closed network connection`. On my local firewall, the logs are showing the session ended due to a `tcp-fin` packet - meaning the remote server closed the session.

From within cPanel I use the `Terminal` app to emulate a console session and I am able to get root command line: `[root@sX-X-X-X ~]#`. From there I then ssh to itself: `ssh username@x.x.x.x` - and I get this error: `dup() in/out/err failed`

I restarted the sshd and the problem persists. What can I do or look at to get this resolved?

## UPDATE:

Ran this debug command from prompt:

```
[root@X.X.X.X ~]# ssh -vvvo PreferredAuthentications=password userID@X.X.X.X
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to X.X.X.X [X.X.X.X] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 0/0
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/identity-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_5.3
debug1: match: OpenSSH_5.3 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_5.3
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: Wrote 864 bytes for a total of 885
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-dss-cert-v00@openssh.com,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: ssh-rsa,ssh-dss
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,arcfour256,arcfour128,aes128-cbc,3des-cbc,blowfish-cbc,cast128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,arcfour,rijndael-cbc@lysator.liu.se
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: hmac-md5,hmac-sha1,umac-64@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-ripemd160,hmac-ripemd160@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-96,hmac-md5-96
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit:
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: kex_parse_kexinit: reserved 0
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug2: mac_setup: found hmac-sha1
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1 none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<2048<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug3: Wrote 24 bytes for a total of 909
debug2: dh_gen_key: priv key bits set: 161/320
debug2: bits set: 1000/2048
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug3: Wrote 272 bytes for a total of 1181
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host 166.62.85.95 filename /root/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: host 166.62.85.95 filename /root/.ssh/known_hosts
debug3: check_host_in_hostfile: match line 1
debug1: Host 'X.X.X.X' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /root/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug2: bits set: 1030/2048
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug2: kex_derive_keys
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: Wrote 16 bytes for a total of 1197
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug3: Wrote 52 bytes for a total of 1249
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/identity ((nil))
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /root/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug3: Wrote 84 bytes for a total of 1333
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password
debug3: preferred password
debug3: authmethod_lookup password
debug3: remaining preferred:
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled password
debug1: Next authentication method: password
userID@X.X.X.X's password:

debug3: packet_send2: adding 48 (len 72 padlen 8 extra_pad 64)
debug2: we sent a password packet, wait for reply
debug3: Wrote 148 bytes for a total of 1481
Segmentation fault
```

## UPDATE 2:

I have tried ssh via several different user accounts, even `root` -- I get the same results for all users.  Here is the user output info:

```
$ grep userID /etc/passwd
$ userID:x:501:501::/home/userID:/bin/bash

$ ls -1 /proc/1121/fd | wc -l
4
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-max
262144
$ cat /proc/sys/fs/file-nr
139584  0       262144


$ df -h
Filesystem         Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/ploop34902p1  118G   14G  100G  12% /
none               2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
none               2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm
```

Also reboot did nothing, still unable to ssh.

## UPDATE 3:

From my SSH logs, its accepting the password and then immediately closing the session:

```
Apr 21 11:44:09 sX.X.X.X sshd[23144]: Accepted password for myAdminID from 47.200.121.187 port 4283 ssh2
Apr 21 11:44:09 sX.X.X.X sshd[23144]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session opened for user myAdminID by (uid=0)
Apr 21 11:44:10 sX.X.X.X sshd[23144]: pam_unix(sshd:session): session closed for user myAdminID
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107254/discussion-on-question-by-rolinger-server-is-failing-ssh-connections).

Comment: Ok, this is annoying.  Why does someone get to downvote my OP without reason or explanation?  This is a very valid thread with well documented troubleshooting info.  But in the last 7 days....this shows a `-10` against my reputation.

Comment: There are no downvotes on this question. But yes, one user decided to remove their upvote (you can see this if you look at [the reputation tab](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/408543/rolinger?tab=reputation) on your profile; note the "unupvote"). But that's just the way the sites work: people are free to vote as they choose.

Answer (score 0):

I realize that this question is from nearly a year ago, but I too ran into this issue, and I've found this question floating around other places online.

The gist is:

- You are running CentOS 6
- You connect the SSH server, client
  immediately segfaults, sometimes spits out `dup() in/out/err failed`
- Logs show successful connection and that the client is closing the
  connection.

What happened is that your server got a bad OpenSSH update - 5.3p1-269.el6.x86_64

You can verify this by running:
`yum --showduplicates list  openssh-server\*`

You need to remove this version, and install the older version over it:

```
rpm -qa openssh*
rpm -e --nodeps openssh-server-5.3p1-269.el6.x86_64
rpm -e --nodeps openssh-5.3p1-269.el6.x86_64
rpm -e --nodeps openssh-clients-5.3p1-269.el6.x86_64
yum -y update openssh
```

In my case, the ssh executable was also set as immutable, check for the `I` flag:

```
lsattr /usr/sbin/sshd
```

Then unset it:

```
chattr -i /usr/sbin/sshd
```

You can then manually re-install openssh-server:

```
yum install  openssh
yum install  openssh-server
yum install  openssh-clients
```

I would reboot, but you can `service sshd restart`

Version should now be:

```
[root@server ~]# ssh -version
OpenSSH_5.3p1, OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
```

Sources:
https://www.godaddy.com/community/VPS-Dedicated-Servers/SSH-accepting-connection-then-dropping-connection/m-p/161332
https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/error-rexec-of-usr-sbin-sshd-failed-no-such-file-or-directory.678129/
https://forums.cpanel.net/threads/unable-to-ssh-or-sftp-able-to-access-whm.671209/